# Swift: create a search bar for a browser

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, browser

Create a web browser using swift and getting error (Editor placeholder in source file) , the search bar should be able to get if the user add http or only www or only add a word to start search in google.com.

```
 func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

     let urlString = mySearchBar.text

if urlString?.starts(with: "http://") ?? <#default value#> || ((urlString?.starts(with: "https://")) != nil){
    loadUrl(urlString!)
} else if (urlString?.contains("www"))!{
    loadUrl("http://\(urlString!)")
}else {
    searchTextOnGoogle(urlString!)

}
}


func loadUrl(_ urlString: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    myWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
}

func searchTextOnGoogle(_ text: String) {
    let textComponents = text.components(separatedBy: " ")

    let searchString = textComponents.joined(separator: "+")

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + searchString) else { return }

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    myWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the placeholder in the code as the error says.. `<#default value#>`

Below code I remove the `<#default value#>` with empty string.

```
 func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

     let urlString = mySearchBar.text

     if urlString?.starts(with: "http://") ?? "" || ((urlString?.starts(with: "https://")) != nil){
         loadUrl(urlString!)
     } else if (urlString?.contains("www"))!{
         loadUrl("http://\(urlString!)")
     }else {
         searchTextOnGoogle(urlString!)
     }
}
```